# Вывод двумерного массива в OpenGL на монитор

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl

Запутался в выводе двумерного массива. У меня есть двумерный массив `A[100][100]`, заполненный случайными числами.

Я написал: `glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, &A);`
Затем: `glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 10000);`
Ошибок компилятора нет, но картинка не выводится. Что ему не нравится? Поглядите пожалуйста )

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glut.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <math.h>
 
#define M 100
#define N 100
#define K 10000
#define F 500
 
int A[M][N] = {0};
int B[M][N] = {0};
 
unsigned int x, y, i, j, n, k;
 
using namespace std;
 
 
unsigned int getRandomNumber(int min, int max)
{
    static const double fraction = 1.0 / (static_cast<double>(RAND_MAX) + 1.0);
    return static_cast<unsigned int>(rand() * fraction * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
 
void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
 
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, &A);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
 
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 100);
 
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
 
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
 
 
void TimerFunction(int value)
{
    glutPostRedisplay();  // перерисовываем экран
    glutTimerFunc(40, TimerFunction, 1);  //запускаем таймер заново.
}
 
 
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(50, 50);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("Проба");
 
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 10, 0, 10, 0, 1);
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glPointSize(8);
 
    for (i = 0; i < K; i++)
    {
        x = getRandomNumber(0, M - 1);
        y = getRandomNumber(0, N - 1);
 
        A[x][y] = 1;
    }
    
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
 
    glutTimerFunc(40, TimerFunction, 1);
 
    glutMainLoop();
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: При вызове glVertexPointer указывается, что там лежат float, а на самом деле int.

Comment: Да, спасибо, исправил на GL_INT.

Нашел, что в glVertexPointer третий параметр как раз отвечает за смещение.
Двумерный массив хранится же в памяти как одномерный, со сдвигами, наверное оно и есть.
glVertexPointer(2, GL_INT, 1, &A);